# How to get column Value Null if row is repeated more than once in Select Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on Select query for the Tableau Dashboard and the condition of the select query is if the query pulls multiple rows for account number, you need to change ProjectStartJobs and LocationEmployees value to Null.

```
SELECT 
    FA.AccountNumber AS AccountNumber
    ,YEAR(New_LandedDate) AS [Year]
    ,FO.New_LandedDate AS LandedDate
    ,FO.CustomerIDName AS Company
    ,FO.New_ProjectStartJobs AS ProjectStartJobs
    ,FA.New_LocationEmployees AS LocationEmployees
    ,FO.New_AnnouncedJobs AS AnnouncedJobs
    ,ISNULL(FA.New_LocationEmployees,0) - ISNULL(FO.new_projectstartjobs,0) AS [Job Creation]
    ,FC.Ecd_ecdregionname AS ECDRegion
    ,FC.Ecd_grandregionname AS GrandDivision
    ,FO.New_TaxTierName AS TaxTier
FROM FilteredOpportunity AS FO
    LEFT JOIN FilteredAccount AS FA
        ON FO.CustomerID = FA.AccountID
    LEFT JOIN FilteredNew_County AS FC
        ON FO.New_CountyID = FC.New_CountyID
WHERE (New_LandedDate >= '2011-01-01'
    AND New_LandedDate <= ( SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(QQ,DATEDIFF(QQ,0,New_LandedDate),0)) FROM FilteredOpportunity ORDER BY New_LandedDate DESC))
    AND (New_AnnouncedJobs >= '50' OR New_ProjectactionCode = '100000000')
    AND new_projectactioncode <> '100000006'
ORDER BY  FA.Accountnumber , [LandedDate] DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function to check how many rows there are for each account, then return null of there is more than 1, e.g.

```
,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FA.AccountNumber) > 1 THEN NULL 
    ELSE FO.New_ProjectStartJobs 
END AS ProjectStartJobs
,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FA.AccountNumber) > 1 THEN NULL 
    ELSE FO.New_LocationEmployees 
END AS LocationEmployees
```

**EDIT**

If the first record for each account should show the value then you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` rather than `COUNT(*) OVER()`:

```
,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FA.AccountNumber ORDER BY [LandedDate] DESC) > 1 THEN NULL 
    ELSE FO.New_ProjectStartJobs 
END AS ProjectStartJobs
,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FA.AccountNumber ORDER BY [LandedDate] DESC) > 1 THEN NULL 
    ELSE FO.New_LocationEmployees 
END AS LocationEmployees
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is showing all values as Null, Only duplicate columns should be Null not the original one.